# I want get to the final result using bluebird map,what's wrong in that code..?

Tags: node.js

I want final result of promise using promise.map, something i have missing over here..?

I have trying using new Promise in my `getdata` function but 
still it's not working...

can anybody help

```
var Promise = require("bluebird");
var array = ["one", "two", "three", "four"];
function getData(data) {
    new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            resolve("this is my data no:" + "one")
        }, 3000)
    }).then((result) => {
        return result
    });
}
Promise.map(array, (item) => {
    getData(item).then((result) => {
        return result
    })
}).then((final) => {
    //I have to print the final result
    console.log(final)
    //["this is my data no:one",
    // "this is my data no:two",
    // "this is my data no:three",
    // "this is my data no:four"]
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to return

```
var Promise = require("bluebird");
var array = ["one", "two", "three", "four"];
function getData(data) {
    // here
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            resolve("this is my data no:" + data)
        }, 3000)
    });
}
Promise.map(array, (item) => {
    // and here
    return getData(item)
}).then((final) => {
    //I have to print the final result
    console.log(final)
    //["this is my data no:one",
    // "this is my data no:two",
    // "this is my data no:three",
    // "this is my data no:four"]
})
```

BTW this part is redundant.

```
.then((result) => {
        return result
    })
```

Comment: Thanks it's working....did you know some other bluebird promise example for multiple call